# Undo function does not work on deletion function

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to implement undo code for my delete function to avoid any accidental deletions on the worksheet by the user.

My undo code works for my update function but does not work for my delete function.

The code runs but the deleted data does not return most of the time when I press `no` button in the save changes message box.

The "undo" function is basically the code returning the `oselect` range (the range I choose with the user input option) when I click `no` to whether I want to save changes.

Here is my code:

```
Sub DatabaseWannabe()

    Dim oselect As Range, vUndo As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oselect = Application.InputBox("Range?", , Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If TypeName(oselect) <> "Range" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If


    oselect.Select
    vUndo = oselect

    Dim rng As Range, rngError As Range, delRange As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select cells to be deleted", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub Else rng.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    For k = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count 'runs through all worksheets

        Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(k)
        With wks
            For i = 1 To 26 '<~~ Loop through columns A to G

                '~~> Check if column has any errors
                On Error Resume Next
                Set rngError = .Columns(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
                    For j = 1 To 200 '<~~ Loop through rows 1 to 100

                        If .Cells(j, i).Text = "#REF!" Then
                            '~~> Store the range to be deleted
                            If delRange Is Nothing Then
                                Set delRange = .Cells(j, i)
                            Else
                                Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Cells(j, i))
                            End If
                        End If

                    Next j
                End If

            Next i
        End With

        If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete
        Set delRange = Nothing

    Next k

    If MsgBox("Save Changes?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        oselect = vUndo
    End If

    '~~> Delete the range in one go

End Sub
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: I can't see which bit of your code is supposed to do the actual 'undo'. You're setting `vUndo` equal to the Range object `oselect` and later on setting `oselect` to `vUndo`, but these are just references to the ranges on the actual worksheet - are you expecting this to change the contents of the worksheet cells?

Comment: Im expecting the oselect range to return back, in the case of which i accidentally make changes to that range. Serves as an "undo" but it does not retrieve back at times @nekomatic

Comment: You might find the `Application.OnUndo` method useful

Comment: If `delRange` and `oselect` have cells in the same area then this will not work as you are deleting cells that were also part of `oselect` - therefore the reference is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to go wrong when you delete the upper part of the first selection (`oselect`), and therefore the range gets invalid. My solution uses another sheet (`shtUndo`) where it copies the 'undo' range to, and in the end it can be copied back.

First you should create (or rename) a sheet for the undo data. I called the sheet *UndoSheet*, and I gave it a name `shtUndo` such that it is accessible as a variable. You can give it a name by going to the VBA editor, then select the sheet, and here you can edit the `(Name)` property.

The updated code is the following:

```
Option Explicit 'A good habit, to track errors beforehand.

Sub DatabaseWannabe()
'define oselect, for undo
Dim oselect As Range
Dim oselectRow As Integer, oselectCol As Integer, _
    oselectRowCount As Integer, oselectColCount As Integer
Dim oselectSht As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
'get oselect
Set oselect = Application.InputBox("Range?", , Selection.Address, , , , , Type:=8)

'check if selection set
If oselect Is Nothing Or oselect.Cells.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No selection set."
    Exit Sub
End If

'define location and size of selection
Set oselectSht = oselect.Parent
oselectRow = oselect.Row
oselectCol = oselect.Column
oselectRowCount = oselect.Cells.Rows.Count
oselectColCount = oselect.Columns.Count

On Error GoTo 0

'now copy data to (hidden) sheet
oselect.Copy
'to keep the values of linked cells, copy by value
'Note: if you want to keep formulas, then remove the parameter `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` (although then deleted reference cells will not be visible anymore).
shtUndo.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
'copy the formatting
shtUndo.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats 

'--- your algorithm ---
Dim rng As Range, rngError As Range, delRange As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim wks As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next

Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select cells To be deleted", Type:=8)

On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub Else rng.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

For k = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count 'runs through all worksheets
  Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(k)

  With wks
    For i = 1 To 26 '<~~ Loop trough columns A to G
        '~~> Check if that column has any errors
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngError = .Columns(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)

        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
            For j = 1 To 200 '<~~ Loop Through rows 1 to 100
                If .Cells(j, i).Text = "#REF!" Then
                    '~~> Store The range to be deleted
                    If delRange Is Nothing Then
                        Set delRange = .Cells(j, i)
                    Else
                        Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Cells(j, i))
                    End If
                End If
             Next j
         End If
     Next i
  End With

  If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete

  Set delRange = Nothing
Next k

If MsgBox("Save Changes?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
    'copy data from undo sheet
    shtUndo.Range("A1").Resize(oselectRowCount, oselectColCount).Copy 
    oselectSht.Cells(oselectRow, oselectCol).PasteSpecial
End If

shtUndo.Cells.Clear

End Sub
```

If you do not want to use a sheet name (i.e. setting the property `(Name)`), you can define it as a variable in the sub:

```
Dim shtUndo As Worksheet
set sht=Sheets("UndoSheet")
```

If you want the user not to see the *UndoSheet*, you can hide it, which you can also do in the sheet properties, accessible through the VBA Editor.

**Update**: to keep the values of linked cells which in the mean time were deleted I use the `PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` function.

*Note 1*: When you for example, on `Sheet1` in `A1` put a reference to another cell: `=A3`, and then delete `A3`, the value of `A1` will be an error: `#REF!`.

*Note 2*: If you have any formulas in the original cells, copying by value (`xlPasteValues`) will copy only the resulting value, not the formula.

Comment: Works perfectly !Thanks a tonne:)

Comment: But i have a small issue here, the code returns the range to the main sheet i delete but does not return the range that has been deleted in the reference sheet. The table of cells reference to each other in two different sheets. I copy paste link these table of cells to another sheet as well and  it does not return that range to the other sheet!

Comment: In what case exactly (i.e. what are you selecting/deleting, is it the same?)? And where does it give this error?

Comment: It gives me error when im asked to select the range shtUndo.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Comment: Are you sure you have set the name of the sheet: `shtUndo`? (Or set it as a variable in the sub, as commented in my answer).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91708/discussion-between-agold-and-niva).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following instead which uses a couple of extra variables to get details about the `oselect` range and the sheet it sits in. If you undo, the code then goes back to the 1st cell that was in this range, resizes the range to fit the `vUndo` array and then writes the array back to the range:

```
Sub DatabaseWannabe()

    Dim oselect As Range, vUndo As Variant, vAdd As String, vSh As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oselect = Application.InputBox("Range?", , Selection.Address, , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If TypeName(oselect) <> "Range" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    vUndo = oselect.Value
    vAdd = oselect.Cells(1).Address
    Set vSh = oselect.Parent

    Dim rng As Range, rngError As Range, delRange As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select cells to be deleted", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub Else rng.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    For k = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count 'runs through all worksheets

        Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(k)
        With wks
            For i = 1 To 26 '<~~ Loop through columns A to G

                '~~> Check if column has any errors
                On Error Resume Next
                Set rngError = .Columns(i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
                    For j = 1 To 200 '<~~ Loop through rows 1 to 100

                        If .Cells(j, i).Text = "#REF!" Then
                            '~~> Store the range to be deleted
                            If delRange Is Nothing Then
                                Set delRange = .Cells(j, i)
                            Else
                                Set delRange = Union(delRange, .Cells(j, i))
                            End If
                        End If

                    Next j
                End If

            Next i
        End With

        If Not delRange Is Nothing Then delRange.Delete
        Set delRange = Nothing

    Next k

    If MsgBox("Save Changes?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then

            vSh.Range(vAdd).Resize(UBound(vUndo, 1) - LBound(vUndo, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(vUndo, 2) - LBound(vUndo, 2) + 1).Value = vUndo

    End If

    '~~> Delete the range in one go

End Sub
```

Comment: getting a type mismtatch error on these lines 
            vSh.Range(vAdd).Resize(UBound(vUndo, 1) - LBound(vUndo, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(Arr, 2) - LBound(Arr, 2) + 1).Value = vUndo

Comment: Copy/Paste typo - my bad. Try the above now I've edited.